Basic Advanced Stats Table in NBA API
I am trying to do something that I thought would be simple but seems somewhat complicated, although maybe I'm missing something. I'm trying to use NBA API to get a dataframe that just shows the standard advanced stats from NBA.com for active players. So literally this table: https://www.nba.com/stats/players/advanced
Is there a simple way to do this?

where's your attempt/code?

No need to use the nba api. You can use the requests to get the data from the api (which returns the json format). Then convert to a dataframe:
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://stats.nba.com/stats/leaguedashplayerstats'
headers = {
    'referer': 'https://www.nba.com/',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/127.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
    }

payload = {
'College': '',
'Conference': '',
'Country': '',
'DateFrom': '',
'DateTo': '',
'Division': '',
'DraftPick': '',
'DraftYear': '',
'GameScope': '',
'GameSegment': '',
'Height': '',
'ISTRound': '',
'LastNGames': '0',
'LeagueID': '00',
'Location': '',
'MeasureType': 'Advanced',
'Month': '0',
'OpponentTeamID': '0',
'Outcome': '',
'PORound': '0',
'PaceAdjust': 'N',
'PerMode': 'PerGame',
'Period': '0',
'PlayerExperience': '',
'PlayerPosition': '',
'PlusMinus': 'N',
'Rank': 'N',
'Season': '2023-24',
'SeasonSegment': '',
'SeasonType': 'Playoffs',
'ShotClockRange': '',
'StarterBench': '',
'TeamID': '0',
'VsConference': '',
'VsDivision': '',
'Weight': '',
    }

jsonData = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=payload).json()

columns = jsonData['resultSets'][0]['headers']
rows = jsonData['resultSets'][0]['rowSet']

df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=columns)

Output:
print(df)
     PLAYER_ID         PLAYER_NAME  ... FGA_PG_RANK  FG_PCT_RANK
0      1631260            AJ Green  ...         143          147
1      1630639           AJ Lawson  ...         193           90
2       203932        Aaron Gordon  ...          58           27
3      1630174       Aaron Nesmith  ...          72          104
4      1630598       Aaron Wiggins  ...         111           59
..         ...                 ...  ...         ...          ...
209    1630178        Tyrese Maxey  ...           2           69
210    1628976  Wendell Carter Jr.  ...          86          134
211    1631111   Wendell Moore Jr.  ...         175          107
212    1630214      Xavier Tillman  ...         181           18
213    1630192          Zeke Nnaji  ...         181            8

[214 rows x 78 columns]

